# Error: Unable to run bash (Ubuntu app) on Windows 10 CMD

Tags: windows-10

I have recently installed Ubuntu app on my Windows 10 (64 bit) machine (OS Build 16299.371, Version 1709). The app opens and works fine. However, when I try to `Right-click>Run As Administrator`, the the app gives error:

```
Error: 0x80070005
```

Also, when I try to run `bash` from Windows CMD, I get the same error:

```
Error: 0x80070005
Press any key to continue...
```

My machine is on a network domain and is given usual "user rights" by the IT administrator. I was wondering that are these errors related and someone can suggest me a workaround to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to edit your question to include which build of Windows 10 you are using.  The solution to your problem will be determined by which build you are using.

Comment: Just added the OS build and version number. Thank you.

Comment: By chance were you using WSL, when you had 1703, installed?  Because your method of launching Ubuntu WSL seems outdated.  Did this WSL instance recently stop working?

Comment: @Ramhound: I didn't have version 1703 installed. It is the domain based machine. I got it installed with version 1709. So, I can not tell you that WSL instance stopped working. Any clue what's happening with version 1709?

Comment: Do you have the OpenSSH Beta Windows Feature enabled by chance?  The error you received is a permission error.  I suggest you reset the instance (by removing it and installing it again) to solve the problem.  If that solves your problem I will find the duplicate which I answered with the appropriate instructions.

Comment: To have bash/Linux like environment, I tried to activate Developer mode. It turned on but with error 0x800f0954. Then, the above errors I described in my question. I don't know if this errors are related. I mentioned before my machine is on network domain so it might lack some IT permissions. What do you think?

Comment: Developer mode isn't required for Windows Subsystem for Linux since you are running 1709. Which is the reason I asked if you had ran 1703 or an earlier version of Windows 10 where it was required.  Your question makes no mention of the fact you are connected to a Active Directory domain.

Comment: My bad. I just edited my question. I don't think so I had any previous version installed. It switched from Windows 7 to 10 and it was a fresh w10 installation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77081/discussion-between-ramhound-and-jibran-khan).